# node.js Array Json

Tags: node.js, json, promise, socket.io

There is an array of JSON. After decoding this JSON data, I want to save it as JSON again and send the data. But I don't know how to send the data correctly. Please use for and promise to find an answer.

```
var AES256cryto = function (KeyValue) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var encrypt = ((val) => {
            let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', ENC_KEY, IV);
            let encrypted = cipher.update(val, 'utf8', 'base64');
            encrypted += cipher.final('base64');

            return encrypted;
        });

        //if (err) return reject(err);
        resolve(encrypt(KeyValue));
    });
}

var AES256decrypt = function (KeyValue) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var decrypt = ((encrypted) => {
            let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', ENC_KEY, IV);
            let decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted, 'base64', 'utf8');

            return (decrypted + decipher.final('utf8'));
        });

        resolve(decrypt(KeyValue));
    });
}
```

```
if (rows) {
        var userinfoArray = new Array();

        for (var i = 0; i < rows.rows.length; i++) {
            Promise.all([AES256decrypt(rows.rows[i].admin), AES256decrypt(rows.rows[i].email), AES256decrypt(rows.rows[i].name)])
                .then(([adminDecrypt, emailDecrypt, nameDecrypt]) => {
                    var userinfo = new Object();

                    userinfo.admin = adminDecrypt;
                    userinfo.email = emailDecrypt;
                    userinfo.name = nameDecrypt;

                    userinfoArray.push(userinfo);
                }).catch(callback);


        }

    socket.emit('UserDataOK', userinfoArray);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem here in this snippet

```js
var userinfoArray = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < rows.rows.length; i++) {
    Promise.all([AES256decrypt(rows.rows[i].admin), AES256decrypt(rows.rows[i].email), AES256decrypt(rows.rows[i].name)])
        .then(([adminDecrypt, emailDecrypt, nameDecrypt]) => {
            var userinfo = new Object();

            userinfo.admin = adminDecrypt;
            userinfo.email = emailDecrypt;
            userinfo.name = nameDecrypt;

            userinfoArray.push(userinfo);
        }).catch(callback);


}

socket.emit('UserDataOK', userinfoArray);
```

is that the statment

```
socket.emit('UserDataOK', userinfoArray);
```

is not guaranteed to be executed after the array is initialized with all the for loop data because it's being processed asynchronously here.

You could move this line to the last promise adding an element to your array like this:

```js
var userinfoArray = new Array();
let expected_array_length = rows.rows.length;

for (var i = 0; i < rows.rows.length; i++) {
    Promise.all([AES256decrypt(rows.rows[i].admin), AES256decrypt(rows.rows[i].email), AES256decrypt(rows.rows[i].name)])
        .then(([adminDecrypt, emailDecrypt, nameDecrypt]) => {
            var userinfo = new Object();

            userinfo.admin = adminDecrypt;
            userinfo.email = emailDecrypt;
            userinfo.name = nameDecrypt;

            userinfoArray.push(userinfo);
            if(userinfoArray.length == expected_array_length) {
                socket.emit('UserDataOK', userinfoArray);
            }
        }).catch(function(err){expected_array_length -= 1; callback(err)}); // decrease rows.rows.length on your callback for each failing insert
}
```

That way, you will guarantee that the message is sent with the last promise resolved.

Another way is to define a promise that indicate the finish of filling the array so that you can continue running your code while this promise resolves and then sends the message immediately. By defining

```
const fillData = function(){
    var userinfoArray = new Array();
    return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.rows.length; i++) {
            try{
            [adminDecrypt, emailDecrypt, nameDecrypt] = await Promise.all([AES256decrypt(rows.rows[i].admin), AES256decrypt(rows.rows[i].email), AES256decrypt(rows.rows[i].name)])
            var userinfo = new Object();

            userinfo.admin = adminDecrypt;
            userinfo.email = emailDecrypt;
            userinfo.name = nameDecrypt;

            userinfoArray.push(userinfo);
            } catch(err){
                callback(err)
            }
        }
        resolve(userinfoArray)
    })
}
```

You could call it as follows to send message on promise resolution

```
fillData(rows)
.then(function(userinfoArray){
    socket.emit('UserDataOK', userinfoArray);
}, function(err){})
```

Comment: Thank you. Thanks to you, I was able to solve the long-held problem perfectly. And thank you for suggesting my wrong intelligence and better ways.